# CSS grid item positioning, where item 1 stays at the lower end of the grid column and item 2 stays in the center of its column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid, positioning

I am trying to achieve this using css grid:

a grid with two columns in the main section. The item in the left column is an image and has to stick to the bottom of the grid while a card will be in second column. The card will be center aligned.

This is my HTML/CSS codes:

```css
.mainbody {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 2fr);
  text-align: center;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  padding-top: 75px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

.left-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container mainbody">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="left-bottom">
      <img class="image-car" src="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      //card text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code does the job, but its not working in media queries. I am a beginner, let me know what changes I need to do, or what approach should i follow to achieve my goal.

Comment: we are missing your image . do you need a 600px height row with an image standing at the bottom ? or is it the image always at bottom while the text grows aside ?

Comment: The image is always at the bottom of the grid column. I was not able to stick it to the bottom any other way therefore i used a 600px height container inside the grid column and later adjusted my image in it.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YdPUTf0oiMUgj68o6ftCDXLcukXUbkz5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I've added the i mage link in the above comment

Comment: okay, is this what you try to do ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wvGXKKG (if you use flex or grid, float and absolute are somehow useless ;) )

Comment: So how can I make one grid item stick to the bottom while other in the center? Also, yes I want something like the grid_layout in your above link.

Comment: if you something at the bottom and aside at the center, then the box itself must be higher, do you mean it is supposed to fill the screen height at the mimum ?

Comment: I added 2 snippet in a below answser , i'll be back later .

Comment: do you need al those elements? (like the `.left`, `.left-bottom`, `.container`, etc) or you just added them for positioning? I think you can simplify the html and reduce a lot of the css (no need of float for example) but it's not clear to me what you do need and what you don't need

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten the CSS code and use `margin` inside a grid cell to push the content towards any edges or center.

Just IMHO *float or absolute should not be of any use while building a layout with grid or flex.*

example:

```css
.mainbody {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  text-align: center;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  }

.left {
margin-top:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container mainbody">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="left-bottom">
      <img class="image-car" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x150&text=1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

codepen to play with: https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wvGXKKG

from your comment:

> So how can I make one grid item stick to the bottom while other in the center? Also, yes I want something like the grid_layout in your above link

possible approach

```css
* {
  margin: auto;
}

.mainbody {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  text-align: center;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #bee
}

.container .container {
  display: grid; /* just a single cel to use layout properties */
}

.left {
  margin: auto auto 0;
}

.card {
  margin: auto 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container mainbody">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="left-bottom">
      <img class="image-car" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x150&text=1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
        tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It did a great job when my card height is according to the picture link I attached. But when the size of the card is slightly smaller, the space above the image section isn't visible, since our top-margin is auto.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vONs2TggTE9yNLiLnZfcFsMWomAwsYOs/view?usp=sharing   This kinda thing isn't working :(( Your solution is though the mosttt reasonable solution on the internet. !!! Thankyou